# class、interfaceまたはenumがありません のエラー

Tags: android, java

アンドロイドスタジオでアプリを作っているのですが、６個のclass、interfaceまたはenumがありません のエラーが出ました。
MainActivity.javaには以下のように記載しました。

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.feminine);
    }


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bigfig);
         imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.bigfig);
    }
 }
```

他の方のエラーを見ているとこのエラーは{}の数が足りないから出るありますがやはりそこなのでしょうか？

Comment: メニューから `Build > Rebuild Project` を選択すると再度コンパイルが実行され、(エラーが有るのであれば)エラーメッセージが表示されます。そのエラーを正確に記載してみてください。現在の情報から察するに、添付されているソースコード以外の箇所に根本的な問題があります。

Answer (score 1):

> class、interfaceまたはenumがありません

というより、`onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`が2つあることのほうが問題があると思います。
{}の数は大丈夫だと思ったのですが…
どちらかのonCreateを消す、引数変更、名前を変更などをしてみてください。
そうでなかったたら別のソースコードに問題が発生しているっぽいです。
もしかしたらエラーメッセージが違うのかも。

Answer (score 1):

{} に問題はなく

- onCreate が2つある
- R がどこにも定義されてない

からでしょう

Comment: `R`というのはXMLから生成されるクラスですね。（https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html）ソース内に定義が現れることもないです。